# YOLO darknet training in R

Tags: r, yolo, darknet

I installed the package to use YOLO Darknet in R and it works. I follow the steps to detect my custom objects following the indications until the steps 7 "https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects"

Now I would like to train it on my custom objects to get the result yolo-obj_final.weights but I did not find how to do in R. Is it possible ?

The way described is Step 8 Start training by using the command line:
    darknet.exe detector train data/obj.data yolo-obj.cfg darknet53.conv.74

How to do it in R instead of using command line ?